# How to replace the last two number from this string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of text like `https://test.com/id/3/5000/333` and I would like to replace the last number `5000` and `3000` with any arbitrary number.
How to do it using regular expression in javascript?
Thanks

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You do not have `3000` in your url. Please show expected output for 3 or more URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\d+/\d+$` to match two consecutive groups of digits separated by a slash before the end of the string.

```js
let s = 'https://test.com/id/3/5000/333';
let res = s.replace(/\d+\/\d+$/, 123 + '/' + 456);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you had queryParams? You can try to construct a `URL` object from the original URL string and manipulate the `pathname`.

```js
const randomInt = (limit) => Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);

const originalUrl = 'https://test.com/id/3/5000/333?test=true';
const urlObj = new URL(originalUrl);
const parts = urlObj.pathname.split('/').filter(path => path.length);

// Modify the last and second-to-last path values
parts[parts.length - 1] = randomInt(1000);
parts[parts.length - 2] = randomInt(10000);

// Re-join the parts of the path
urlObj.pathname = parts.join('/');

const modifiedUrl = urlObj.toString();

console.log(modifiedUrl);
```